# Error changing Mac address of usb adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I want to change the mac address of my usb adaper. I just resently installed the mt7610u driver. so i did this:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo ifconfig ra0 down
sudo ifconfig ra0 hw ether 02:00:00:00:00:0A
sudo ifconfig ra0 up
sudo service network-manager start
```

and i get the following error for the 3rd line:

`SIOCSIFHWADDR: Operation not supported`

I installed macchanger and tried changing it but got:

`[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Operation not supported`

I dont know if its somthing with the driver or what.

Kindly refer to picture below:
[image: command]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is:

```
SIOCSIFHWADDR: Operation not supported
```

which means that your module or hardware do not allow you to change the MAC address

Comment: If it is with the driver, is there something else can do to change the mac address.